# AngularJs : Referencing to the value of an object inside angular {{ }} html markup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object like this:

```
items = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}];
lists = [a,b];
```

Then this is my markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
          // I want to display like this
          {{ item.{{list}} }}
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not try it like {{item}}.{{list}}? Since these are different objects with properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it in the following manner :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
      {{item[list]}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the lists array should have quotes around the a and b...

```
lists = ['a','b'];
```

then the markup should be...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
        {{item[list]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays should be like,

```
$scope.items = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}];
$scope.lists = ["a","b"];
```

Html should be like,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
    {{item[list]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Now this will work.